# Excel formula to sum up monthly sales

Tags: excel-formula

I search for a simple solution to avoid that long formula, that i use to sum up and multiply specific cells.

For example: To get sum in march i need to multiply number of "item 01" in that month with price and that for each item in that month.

So i need write for each cell(item): `=$C$2*E2` = Item 01; `=$C$3*E3` = Item 02 and so on.

It's not a problem as long i need to use only few items, but it gets sometimes pretty long with over 40 items. It's annying to write it.

[image: Example]

How it works:
Column A - Item name
Column B Number of items total
Column C price of one item
Column E-G - how many of items were sold in each month.

It is calculated in Cell 15 Result. Each number of items from month is multiplied throught right item price and summed up in one cell.

I searched after solution online, but without success

Example:
`=$C$2*E2+$C$3*E3+$C$5*E5+$C$6*E6+$C$7*E7+$C$8*E8+$C$9*E9+$C$10*E10+$C$13*E13+$C$14*E14`

Comment: Try SUMPRODUCT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B2:$B14,$E2:$E14)
```

Place the above in E15 and copy it to the right as needed.  It will do every row.  You current version looks like it skips items 03, 10 and 11.

Comment: yea I skipped them for a reason in my original data table. Thx it works!

Comment: If you want to skip a particular row like column B for value less than 10 you would just need to add that as one of the range and convert the TRUE/FALSE to a number by sending it through a math operator.  Your formula would look something like:  `=SUMPRODUCT($B2:$B14,$E2:$E14, --($B2:$B14<10))`  conversly you could add a column called  "Included" and it could be populated with yes/no  then it would simply be ` --($Q2:$Q14="yes")` that gets added to the formula